# Finding the equation of a line given two points on the line

Tags: geometry

I have the question "The straight line L passes through the points $A(-6,8)$ and $B(3,2)$

a) Find an equation of the line $L$

b) Show that the point $C(9, -2)$ lies on $L$.

"

So for part a) I got the answer of $y = -2/3X + 4$

but i'm not quite sure how I would do part $B$. Please could you show your working so i understand this better.

Comment: If the equation of the line is $y- -2/3x + 4$ then the line consists of all the points (j,k) and only the points (j,k) where $k = -2/3j + 4$. That's what the equation of a line *means*. Does $-2 = -2/3(9) + 4$?  If it does, then that point is on the line.  If it doesn't, then it isn't.

Comment: Ah i see. Yes -2 does equal -2/3(9)+4. So should i leave the final answer as -2 = -2/3(9) + 4 ?  or should i solve the equation and leave it as -2 = -2 ? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an equation of a line as well as a point that, in theory, lies on that line. Plug the x and y values for point C into your equation from a). You'd have $-2 = \frac{-2}{3}(9) +4$, and go from there...

Comment: By the way (for Dan), you can check that the equation you found in (a) is correct by plugging the coordinates of $A$ and $B$ instead of $C$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$ where $(x_1,y_1)$ is a point on the line and $m$ is the gradient.

If the line passes through $(-6,8)$ and $(3,2)$ then the gradient is
$$m = \frac{\mathrm{difference \ \ in} \ \ y}{\mathrm{difference \ \ in} \ \ x} 
=\frac{8-2}{-6-3}=\frac{6}{-9}=-\frac{2}{3}$$

Given that the line passes through $(x_1,y_1)=(3,2)$ and has gradient $m=-\frac{2}{3}$, an equation is
$$y-2=-\tfrac{2}{3}(x-3)$$

To show that $(x,y)=(9,-2)$ lies on a line, substitute $x=9$ and $y=-2$ into the equation for the line and check that it works. For example, does the following work:
$$-2-2=-\tfrac{2}{3}(9-3)$$